# Android app to retreive images and text from a website

Tags: android

I want to make an android app that retrieves a list and images from a website,displays  and get updates it ,Im well versed in d display and have knowledge of Java..What would I need to know?

Comment: I just started,Its just like making an app to show a list of Cars,images and details just to learn,which part would I explore..Will I require access to the compaby's original website or will I be constantly updating my data

Comment: you may like to check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/08/download-image-from-url-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you want to retrieve information  from the internet and store it in a ListView?

You can get data from the internet by XML Parsing:
1. You cou use DOM Parsing
2. SAX Parsing
3. Or the most efficient way, Pull Parsing

You may have to update it yourself; or you could parse the website, this is more difficult but its possible, if you use something like [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

There is a great [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html) for PullParsing on the Android Dev Site.

There are also a lot of tutorials about ListViews and retrieving images. E.g. [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Next time if you expect somebody to answer, provide more information and what you have already tried.

Comment: So Sire,Would I need access to the website's database and all the 'REST' and 'Json' mumbo-jumbo are not neede here,Are they?

Comment: And I mean retreiving text and images from a website that would be constantly updated like a car website,store website and I wouod probably need to store it in a cache,wont I?

Comment: if you chose to parse the HTML from the Website with jSoup. And you write it well, then you won't need to update anything. But it's quite a heavy task(for some sites). But it's definately doable :)

Comment: Does XML pull parsing also give me the ability not to update anything after I write my code like JSoup

Comment: And I think XML parsing is also for websites that provide XML code too,Kindly answer both questions...I understand ur explanations