# How to retreive items from websites into android app

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android app to retreive images and text from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073291/android-app-to-retreive-images-and-text-from-a-website)

How do I retreive images and text and display it in my android application,Like getting picture of cars and the car details from a car website if I am to write an app for car dealer

Comment: you will have to use web service for this purpouse can you be more specific

Comment: You've asked the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you might

1. use web service of the website for getting fluxs(in the format of json, xml...)
2. create a parser in your app to interpret flux into objects Java
3. use android's views (ImageView TextView...) to display on the screen.

I hope you can get it, this is the very common case of an app.

Comment: Kindly explain the first step please

Answer (score 0):

You should seek for data feed in these websites. If you find any link that returns data in JSON,XML, etc. format, you can parse it in your app and use it.
For example, you can check out [twitter status api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: Been getting different versions of this answer,Can u kindly explain  the part before "parse it in your app and u can use it"